# ffmpeg - Strip specific audio track from multiple files with batch script

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, batch

I am trying to create a batch script that will strip a specific audio track from multiple video files using "ffmpeg".

The audio track has the same ID on all files.
after performing "ffmpeg -i file.mkv I get:
[image]

What I want to do is strip the DTS-HD MA audio track. So I created a batch script:

```
if not exist muxed md muxed
for %%g in (*.mkv) do (
    ffmpeg -i %%g -map 0:1 -c copy muxed\%%g
)
```

But unfortunately what it does is it strips video track and second audio track (DDP 5.1)

I have tried other ID combos also:

- 0:0 - Strips both audio tracks
- 0:1 - Strips video track and second audio track (DDP 5.1)
- 0:2 - Strips video track and first audio track (DTS-HD MA)

I simply want it to strip the DTS-HD MA track. the closest I came was with 0:2 but that also removed the video track.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out on my own.

Solution:

```
if not exist DDP md DDP
for %%g in (*.mkv) do (
  ffmpeg -i %%g -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -c copy DDP\%%g
)
```

This will leave out the audio track with ID 0:1